# unique image name for each user

Tags: php, database, algorithm, amazon-s3

Imagine I'm building a blog system where a user can upload images for a blog post. I have a problem mapping the uploaded images with user and their blog post.

Here's the flow :

1. User uploaded some pictures, it's saved to the server.
2. I store the image name in the related table, means later I can
   retrieve images by blog's post_id.

But what if the user upload images that has the same file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the time in the file name.

With:

```
time()
```

Comment: Will I have difficulties retrieving the images?

Comment: No not at all, this will display the current date in the format timestamp. E.g filename_1417016126.jpg

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler The idea would be to use the blog post's date and time along with the file name, since i'm extra paranoid about collision, i'd add a little something extra in there too, just to make sure there wont be collisions if the file name of an image and the time is the same as of another blog post. This is a rare case however.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for a file name that's structured like

userID_blogpostID_filename

Oh and as for the same file name problem, just do a simple check, and rename the file if a file of the same name exists.

And as manudog's answer suggested, you could add the unix time along with the filename to avoid that from happening.

Comment: the first 2 identifier doesn't help because the file name still can be the same.

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler Quoted from OP' question
" I have a problem mapping the uploaded images with user and their blog post."

That first two identifiers for that purpose, and of course the third identifier being the file name, which would be modified if the file name existed. Perhaps my answer wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Append a serial ID to every file name, such as an integer that you increment every time.

Comment: This is similar to the timestamp idea by Manudog.